# Using socket in omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to send a packet from application layer at sender node directly to mac layer and then  to a specific application at the receiver node.

```
 
*.S.numApps = 1
*.S.app[0].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.S.app[0].io.destAddress = "destination"
*.S.app[0].io.destPort = 1000
*.S.app[0].source.displayStringTextFormat = "sent %p pk (%l)"
*.S.app[0].source.packetLength = 1200B
*.S.app[0].source.productionInterval = truncnormal(100us,50us)

# destination application
*.R.numApps = 1
*.R.app[0].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.R.app[0].io.localPort = 1000
```

Error: handleMessage(): Unknown protocol: protocolId = 63, protocolName = udp, servicePrimitive = REQUEST, pathStartGate = NN.S.app[0].io.socketOut, pathEndGate = NN.S.sc.in[2] -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) NN.S.sc (id=12), during network initialization

Please give me an example of how I can send this packet to a specific application at the receiver  node using only application/ mac and physical layers.

[image][image]

##################################

I also tried to use this, but the packet never arrived to the sink app.  (please check the attached picture)

```
# source application
*.S.numApps = 1
*.S.app[0].typename = "EthernetSourceApp"
*.S.app[0].display-name = "source"

*.S.app[0].interfaceTable.displayAddresses = true
 
*.*.app[*].source.packetLength = 1B
*.*.app[*].source.productionInterval = 1ms  
*.*.app[*].sink.consumptionInterval  = 1ms  
 
 
 
# destination application
*.R.numApps = 1
*.R.app[0].typename = "EthernetSinkApp"
*.R.app[0].display-name = "dest"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two questions in a single SO question... but:

1. Yes, the error "Unknown protocol" is to be expected as you are sending an UDP packet on a node that does not have UDP or IP layers... This is essentially a switch, so only RAW ethernet packets should be sent. Which leads to the second part (this is a good direction,), but...
2. I don't see anywhere in the INI file where you specified the destination address, where the packets should be sent, so no wonder they are not arriving.

Comment: Thank you, I want to send whatever packets from application layer directly to mac layer.
1. Is this possible ?
2. How?

Comment: Yes. See the applications/ethernet folder. You can open an llc socket that directly talks to the link layer goind around the transport and network layers. You can install such an application directly into a StandardHost. It will just directly send the packets to the link layer routing around the transport/network layers.

Effectively, what you did in your second attempt. The only proble, you forgot to specify a destination address there.

Comment: I tried many alternatives to this "remoteAddress" address. but he same error is thrown:
*.S.app[0].io.remoteAddress =  "NN.R.app[0].sink"
  
"
L3AddressResolver: IInterfaceTable not found as submodule  `interfaceTable' in host/router `NN.R.app[0].sink' -- in module (inet::EthernetSocketIo) NN.S.app[0].io (id=34), during network initialization "

Comment: The remote address is either the HW address of the remote hosts ethernet interface i.e. something (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) or the path of the NODE that is also resolved (i.e. not the module path to the application module like you wrote, but th enode). = "NN.R"